# iPhone Configuration Utility does not install MDM Configuration profile

Tags: iphone, plist, mdm, magic-numbers

The setup:
iPhone Configuration Utility for Windows, version 3.5.0.289
iPhone (3G?) Software version 4.3.5 (8L1)

Default MDM configuration. The MDM service is using Apple's Ruby reference implementation if it matters.

When trying to install a profile using IPCU, configured in iPCU, which IPCU considers valid, I get the following error:

```
Oct  4 15:39:46 Developments-iPhone profiled[644] <Warning>: MC|Profile cannot be queued for installation. Error: NSError 0x1f5510d0:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
Sugg   : The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
US Desc: Invalid Profile
US Sugg: The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
Code   : 4000
Type   : MCFatalError
...Underlying error:
NSError 0x1f550960:
Desc   : The profile MDMTest is invalid.
Sugg   : The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
US Desc: The profile MDMTest is invalid.
US Sugg: The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
MDMTest
)
...Underlying error:
NSError 0x1f54f940:
Desc   : The payload MDMTest is invalid.
Sugg   : The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
US Desc: The payload MDMTest is invalid.
US Sugg: The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
Code   : 2000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
MDMTest
)
...Underlying error:
NSError 0x1f54f9b0:
Desc   : The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
US Desc: The MDM payload com.example.mdmtest.mdm1 contains invalid access rights.
Domain : MCMDMErrorDomain
Code   : 12000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
"com.example.mdmtest.mdm1"
)
Extra info:
{
isPrimary = 1;
}
```

My question is this: What is "isPrimary = 1", where does it come from, and how do I get rid of it? I've tried exporting the configuration, but that doesn't contain any "isPrimary = 1" element and the access rights field is a magic number, presumably a bitmask, which I haven't been able to locate any documentation for, so is there any process, other than randomly trying numbers, by which one could get the iPhone to accept this profile?

Comment: Can you post the XML that makes up the payload you are trying to installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error relates to invalid access rights (the options you select that you want to manage with MDM) and you are running iOS 4. I imagine you have selected the "Add/Remove Apps" access right, which isn't supported by iOS 4. Turn off this access right, and also the "Add/Remove Settings" right and try to install it again.

Comment: Thanks now I get different, but more meaningful error messages, that I can figure out on my own. :)

Out of curiosity, is there some way to manually calculate the AcessRights magic number, or will I have to reverse engineer it, one right at a time? Also is there a list of which rights/software version are compatible, or is that also a matter of trial and error?

Comment: Never mind, found it. [link](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobiledevicemanagementprotocol.pdf)